# How to fix Unbound Local Error: local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I want to develop a script that convert Measuring units based in user input . and after the script run to last code it give me this error (Unbound Local Error: local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment)

python v is 3.7.3.
as I mentioned above (and I am new to python ) the script is convert Measuring units based on user input but it give me this error  . so
I’ve tried different way by moveing  print function from the bottom my function  it worked with the error but not with actual script because it give my "none"

python

```
def convart(MU , oMU , NUM):
    if MU.lower == "in" and oMU.lower =="cm":
        answer= float(NUM)* 2.54
        print("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM,MU.upper,MUcm,oMU.upper))
    elif MU.lower == "cm" and oMU.lower =="in":
        answer= float(NUM) / 2.54
        print("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM,MU.upper,answer,oMU.upper))
    # return ("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM,MU.upper,answer,oMU.upper))

Fmu = input("Please Enter your Measuring unit >>")
Smu= input("Please Enter Measuring units you want to convert to >>")
number = input(" Enter the number >>")
print(convart(Fmu,Smu,number))
```

“I expect the output of 2 in is = 5.08 cm , but the actual output "None"

Comment: Your code runs fine, so I couldn't reproduce the UnboundLocalError (please post a [mre] if you want to get this fixed). Regarding the output of `None`: you're not returning anything from the function, and the return value defaults to `None`.

Comment: `MUcm` is not defined, you have not set it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all your calls to `lower` with `lower()` (and similarly replace `upper` with `upper()`), so your function would look like this:

```
def convart(MU , oMU , NUM):
    if MU.lower() == "in" and oMU.lower() == "cm":
        answer = float(NUM) * 2.54
        print("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM, MU.upper(), MUcm, oMU.upper()))
    elif MU.lower() == "cm" and oMU.lower() == "in":
        answer = float(NUM) / 2.54
        print("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM, MU.upper(), MUcm, oMU.upper()))
```

However, you're not returning anything from your function, i.e.: it returns `None` by default, so `print(convart(...` will print `None`. So your function must return the variable `answer`:

```
def convart(MU , oMU , NUM):
    answer = 0 # any default value to be returned if neither tests are true
    if MU.lower() == "in" and oMU.lower() == "cm":
        answer = float(NUM) * 2.54
        print("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM, MU.upper(), MUcm, oMU.upper()))
    elif MU.lower() == "cm" and oMU.lower() == "in":
        answer = float(NUM) / 2.54
        print("{} {} is = {} {}".format(NUM, MU.upper(), MUcm, oMU.upper()))
    return answer
```

Comment: I feel stupid now . thank you it worked . side note is there any tool to help me to avoid this mistakes in the future

Answer (score 0):

lower and upper are methods, not keywords. So change lower & upper to lower() and upper().

> "any_string".lower()/upper()